# javascript if(-1) {...statement...} evaluates to true

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a condition where `0` or more is valid and negative is invalid. When I write code accordingly in JavaScript/TypeScript, to my surprise it's not working the way I expected it to.

The code is as follows.

```js
if (-1) {
  console.log("truthy")
} else {
  console.log("falsy")
}
```

And this prints the following in console.

> truthy

It should have be `falsy`, right?

Any help, helping me understand this behavior. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: `-1` is a truthy value. The only falsy values are `0`, `""`, `false`, `undefined`, `null` and `NaN`. *Everything else is truthy*.

Comment: No — not right.

Comment: 0 is considered as a falsy value not -1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are six falsy values in JavaScript:

- `false`
- `0`
- `NaN`
- `undefined`
- `''`
- `null`

*All* other values are truthy.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, 0 is always evaluated to falsy, and any non-zero number is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `non-zero` numbers evaluate to true while zero evaluates to false. Heres a nice webpage that goes deep on the boolean evaluations of many different values in javascript: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/